# Instantaneous word counter

Tags: javascript, web, counter

I'd like to add a word counter to a large text box (think blog editor) that increments with every word that I enter. (i.e. after I type "Hello" it would increment from 0 to 1 and after I write "world" after that it would increment to 2). I'd like to do this within a webpage but I'm happy to consider other options.

I have no idea how to do this. I think there would be a way to do this with Javascript but I know next to nothing about Javascript.

Could someone point me in the direction of figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Step 1: Learn JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good idea to implement this is to check inputed letter (for example, [onKeyUp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event). If previous character was non-space and current is not a letter, then increment count. Detail: if previous character is non-letter, increasing should not be done (double spaces e t.c.)

When user is pressing `Backspace` or `Delete` key, similar check should be done. Key codes you can find [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

The difficult thing with this counting 'on the fly' is to check 'non-key' input. For example, user can use `Ctrl+Insert` combination to copy data from clipboard, or select text in the textbox and then press `Del` key. That should be handled separately if there is real need to avoid whole value processing (which could be really huge)

Comment: but what about deleting spaces?

Comment: yes, deleting should also be watched, I've edited. But the real troubles will be caused by such actions as `select text`+`del` key or copying from clipboard e t.c. And that can also be handled by checking keys pressing. There is a drag-n-drop input.. and there I'm not sure that there is an easy crossbrowser way to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this functionality on the onkeyup event for the textbox.

```
document.getElementById("inputbox").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
   // Get the inputs text.
   var inputVal = e.srcElement.value;
   var counter = 0;
   // Check input isn't empty.
   if(inputVal){
       // Count individual letters.
       var wordlist = inputVal.split(" ");
       for(var i=0;i<wordlist.length;i++)
           if(wordlist[i])
               counter = counter+1;
   }
   // Then set your counter element.
   document.getElementById("counter").value = counter;
});
```

Comment: There's so many things wrong in this code that I'm not sure where to begin. 1) missing `);` at the end, 2) you assume `obj` is the textarea when it's actually the key event, 3) it should be `keyup` not `onkeyup`, 4) won't work if there are line breaks or multiple spaces, ...

Comment: Well the downvote actually came before I had put it into an event function so points 1-3 weren't relevant then, but presumably it was for the only serious problem you listed (since the others are tiny oversights) which is #4.. I dunno how to account for line breaks but if it's a small change I think this is a less messy than the other answer....